# How to get all UserNames/UUIDs Minecraft API

Tags: json, indexing, minecraft

I'm trying to make a program with a functionality similar to [NameMC](https://namemc.com/) but I can't get all of the users of Minecraft.

[NameMC](https://namemc.com/) is an Index of all of the Minecraft users, their name/skin histories among other things.

I've read all of the entries in [Wiki.VG](https://wiki.vg/Mojang_API) but it doesn't seem to contain and endpoint to get literally ALL of the users.

`https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/` would logistically make sense but alas it doesn't exist.

To re-iterate; I do not want to get the data of a user in Minecraft, I want to get a list of all of the usernames in Minecraft.

So how can I get ALL of the Usernames || UUIDs of ALL of the users in Minecraft?

Comment: I am not very familiar with that, but just the thought that an individual would get to know everyone else worries me. I doubt any privacy-aware community would ever expose that.

Answer (score 0):

Mojang of course dont want to collect all data about their players at once and it would be a really big payload, so the other possibility is that you search individually for these players if you need them and cache the information on your database or redis.